# How do you pass arguments to an inner function?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

i have come across the following code today:

```
def deriv(f):
    def df(x):
        h = 0.001
        total = (f(x+h)-f(X))/h
        return round(total, 3)
    return df
def g(x):
    return x*x + 2*x + 2

print(deriv(g)(3))
```

what does it mean to have the 3 after deriv(g) like "deriv(g)(3)? is this how you pass arguments to a function defined inside of another? what exactly is it doing there?

Comment: `()` is how you call a function. It doesn't matter where it is defined. In this case, `deriv(g)` evaluates to a function, so the `(3)` following it calls that function with that argument. This is the same for *any expression which evaluates to a function*

Comment: So, in this case, yes, that is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:
This is nearly like every other function, this just allows you to create functions dynamically

---

lets boil this down a bit

```py
def wrapper(constant) -> Callable:
   def inner(x) -> float:
     return x+constant
   return inner
```

```
foo = wrapper(2)
```

would return you a function like

```py
foo(x):
  return x + 2
```

You can think about it beeing similar to this:

```
wrapper(2)(100) == foo(100)
```

---

In your case `deriv(g)` creates a function and replaces the `f` in `def dx` with your passed function and creates a function where the g is fixed.

It will behave like this:

```
# deriv(g) -> 
dg(x):
    h = 0.001
    total = (g(x+h)-g(X))/h
    return round(total, 3)
return df
```

---